# How to get object id from google map marker?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, hashmap, android-maps-v2

I am using this code to draw markers on google map (hide the ones that are invisible on screen)

```
for (MyMapPointModel item : items) {
            // If the item is within the the bounds of the screen
            if (bounds.contains(item.getLatLng())) {
                // If the item isn't already being displayed
                if (!visibleMarkers.containsKey(item.getId())) {
                    // Add the Marker to the Map and keep track of it with
                    // the HashMap
                    // getMarkerForItem just returns a MarkerOptions object
                    customMarker = getMap().addMarker(getMarkerForItem(item));
                    visibleMarkers.put(item.getId(), customMarker);
                    drawMarker(item.getLatLng(), item.getThumbUri(), item.getId());
                }
            } else { // If the marker is off screen
                // If the course was previously on screen
                if (visibleMarkers.containsKey(item.getId())) {
                    // 1. Remove the Marker from the GoogleMap
                    visibleMarkers.get(item.getId()).remove();
                    // 2. Remove the reference to the Marker from the
                    // HashMap
                    visibleMarkers.remove(item.getId());

                }
            }
        }
```

and i am storing markers with items id in hashmap 
I want to call an activity with details for taped marker and i can't get item id from onMarkerClick listener (he provides only marker object). Am i missing something, and if i am what? Does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below

```
 mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
                        arg0.getId() //get id
                        //use switch case
                        // or use title
                        if(arg0.getTitle().equals("title"))   
                        // do something
                        return true;
                    }

                });
```

Comment: i am using hashmap <integer, Marker>, and my key value is of integer type, field id from database, i don't understand how can i get that value only with arg0(Marker)?

Comment: no, i did not set one. Are you suggesting that i should set my marker title to id?

Comment: @Mm then get the key using the map and use a switch case or if else

Answer (score 1):

> and i am storing markers with items id in hashmap
>   i am using hashmap

I assume that you are using that particular data structure successfully elsewhere and so it is useful.

For your problem, though, it sounds like that you need `HashMap<String, Integer>`, using `getId()` on `Marker` as the key. This will allow you to look up your `Integer` given its `Marker`.

Or, if you are creating your own info window, use the title or snippet fields in a `Marker` to hold a string representation of your integer, so you can use `getTitle()` or `getSnippet()` to retrieve that value directly.

Answer (score 0):

use this code for that

```
 mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
                    if(arg0.getTitle().equals("MyHome")) // if marker source is clicked

                    return true;
                }

            });
```